# How can I add border-radius CSS property to dropdown ant design element?

Tags: css, reactjs, antd, styled-components, ant-design-pro

I want to add border-radius CSS property to my dropdown component from ant design, but I don't know how I can implement it. I tried to change antd-css file, add style object directly into component, but I haven't got result. I use styled-component - if it is useful information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used basic dropdown menu from https://ant.design/components/dropdown/
(Basically opens menu on hover, if this is what you want)

Style:

```
.ant-dropdown-menu  {
  border-radius: 50px;
}
```

[image: Border radius 50px demo screenshot]

**Update as per requirement:**

You can use `style={{ borderRadius: 50 }}` on your *overlay* item.

see below screenshot for reference:
[image: used style on]

Comment: Almost. But how can I do this with css-in-js, using styled-components, without classes? I tried add this class in the end of antd.css file, but didn't get changes.

Comment: Please check above update and modify your code for overlay value that you are passing to the stroy

Comment: Really, I needed pass style to Menu, but not to Dropdown... Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Dropdown } from 'antd'
import { DropDownProps } from 'antd/lib/dropdown'

interface DropdownProps extends DropDownProps {
  children: React.ReactElement
}

const CustomDropdown = ({ children, overlay, placement }: DropdownProps) => {
  return (
    <Dropdown overlay={overlay} placement={placement || 'bottomLeft'}>
      {children}
    </Dropdown>
  )
}
export { CustomDropdown as Dropdown }
```